# ¿Por qué no puedo leer datos de esta ruta del registro de Windows?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy intentando leer datos de las fuentes instaladas a través del registro de Windows. Me impide hacerlo, ya que siempre me aparece el mensaje de *No puede encontrar la ruta de acceso* (he hecho copia y pega, no creo que en eso haya ningún error) . ¿Existe alguna limitación o restricción a la hora de leer datos del registro de Windows? Os dejo mi código:

```
private void ObtenerFontsRegistro()


{
        string ruta1 = @"C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\";
       
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ruta1);
        String linea = null;

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            linea = reader.ReadLine();
            MessageBox.Show(linea);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes leer los datos desde una ruta similar a `"C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\"` utilizando un `StreamReader`. Cuando especificas esa ruta de esa manera estás haciendo referencia a un nombre de directorio (carpeta), no al de un archivo, y los `Stream` operan sobre archivos y no sobre carpetas.

Para obtener los nombres de los archivos en esa carpeta puedes utilizar un código similar a `var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(ruta1)`.

Comment: Gracias. Me di cuenta justo después de escribir el mensaje. Un saludo